# apt update hangs - error message in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I cannot update Ubuntu 16.04 due to the following error:

```
Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
```

How should I proceed in trying to update?